# Issue in creation of Dash app for a first time user

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have created a folder for calculation of CO2 emission. I have created three files, one is configuration.yaml script for defining each excel sheet and parameters, background_prcoessing.py for running calculation of CO2 emission and third Dash app.py for creating dashboard for my app. However, when I run app.py script, it runs but does not display any page. I am using Spyder IDE for writing script. Could some one please explain what I am doing wrong? Here is my code:
Step 1. Configuration.yaml

excel_sheets:

- sheet_name: Fuel

  columns:

  - Activity
  - Emission_source
  - Unit
  - Fuel_consumption
  - Emission_factor
- sheet_name: Bioenergy

  columns:

  - Activity
  - Emission_source
  - Unit
  - Fuel_consumption
  - Emission_factor
- sheet_name: Refrigerant

  columns:

  - Activity
  - Emission_source
  - Unit
  - Refill_quantity
  - Emission_factor
- sheet_name: Passenger_vehicles

  columns:

  - Activity
  - Car_type
  - Fuel_type
  - Unit
  - Distance(km)
  - Emission_factor

Step 2. Background processing code

import pandas as pd

import yaml

def load_config(config_file_path="config.yaml"):

```
with open(config_file_path, "r") as file:

    config = yaml.safe_load(file)

return config
```

## Create a dictionary to store data for each sheet

def process_excel_file(file_path, config):

```
data_by_sheet = {}



# Loop through each sheet

for sheet_config in config['excel_sheets']:

    sheet_name = sheet_config['sheet_name']

    columns = sheet_config['columns']



    data_by_sheet[sheet_name] = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)



    # Extract relevant columns based on sheet configuration

    data_by_sheet[sheet_name] = data_by_sheet[sheet_name][columns]



    # Step 3: Calculate Total Scope 1 emission_kgCO2 for each sheet

    if sheet_name == 'Refrigerant':

        # Calculate Total Scope 1 emission_kgCO2 for Refrigerant sheet

        data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Scope1_emission_kgCO2'] = data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Refill_quantity'] * data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Emission_factor']

    elif sheet_name == 'Passenger_vehicles':

        # Calculate Total Scope 1 emission_kgCO2 for Passenger Vehicles sheet using Vehicles-specific columns

        data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Scope1_emission_kgCO2'] = data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Distance(km)'] * data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Emission_factor']
```

lse:

```
        # Calculate Total Scope1_emission_kgCO2 for other sheets

        data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Scope1_emission_kgCO2'] = data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Fuel_consumption'] * data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Emission_factor']



    # Step 4: Convert Scope 1 emission into tonnes for each conversion factor

    data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Scope1_emission_TonnesCO2'] = data_by_sheet[sheet_name]['Scope1_emission_kgCO2'] / 1000  # 1 Tonne = 1000 kg





#Print Data

print(f'\n{sheet_name} Data: ')

print(data_by_sheet[sheet_name].head())
```

#Save the processed data to an excel file for each sheet

```
output_file = f'{sheet_name}_processed_data.xlsx'

data_by_sheet[sheet_name].to_excel(output_file, index = False)

print(f'\nProcessed data saved to: {output_file}')





return data_by_sheet
```

Step 3. App.py (using Dash)

import dash

from dash import dcc

from dash import html

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

import base64

import io

from background_processing import process_excel_file, load_config

import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

#%matplotlib notebook

import plotly.express as px

#Create a Dash class. The '**name**' parameter is used to determine the root path of the application

app = dash.Dash(**name**)

#Define the layout of the app. Here it is 'html.Div'

app.layout = html.Div([

```
dcc.Upload(

    id='upload-data',

    children=html.Button('Upload Excel File'),

    multiple=False

),

html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
```

])

@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),

```
          [Input('upload-data', 'contents')],

          prevent_initial_call=True)
```

def update_output(contents):

```
if not contents:

    raise PreventUpdate



content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)

file_path = io.BytesIO(decoded)



config = load_config()  # Read config from file



data_by_sheet = process_excel_file(file_path, config)



# Now you can use 'data_by_sheet' for visualization or further analysis

for sheet_name in ['Fuel', 'Bioenergy']:

    # Bar chart with respect to Activity

     fig_activity = px.bar(data_by_sheet[sheet_name], x='Activity', y='Scope1_emission_kgCO2', color='Activity',

                         labels={'Scope1_emission_kgCO2': 'Scope 1 Emission (kgCO2)'}, title=f'{sheet_name} Scope1 Emissions - Activity')

     fig_activity.show()

    # Bar chart with respect to emission_source

     fig_source = px.bar(data_by_sheet[sheet_name], x='Emission_source', y='Scope1_emission_kgCO2', color='Emission_source',

                         labels={'Scope1_emission_kgCO2': 'Scope 1 Emission (kgCO2)'}, title=f'{sheet_name} Scope1 Emissions - Activity')

     fig_source.show()

    #fig_activity.write_image(f'{sheet_name}_graph.jpg')   # For saving as JPG file (optional)

   # Bar chart with respect to fuel_emission_source

     fig_passenger_veh= px.bar(data_by_sheet['Passenger_vehicles'], x='Car_type', y='Scope1_emission_kgCO2', color='Car_type',

                             labels={'Scope1_emission_kgCO2': 'Scope 1 Emission (kgCO2)'}, title=f'{sheet_name} Scope1 Emissions - Fuel Source')

     fig_passenger_veh.show()


# For demonstration, print the first few rows of each sheet

for sheet_name, sheet_data in data_by_sheet.items():

    print(f"\n{sheet_name} Data:")

    print(sheet_data.head())


return 'Processing in the background...'
```

## Run the app.

if **name** == '**main**':

```
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I am trying to figure out the issue but no success. Could someone help me please?